# problem with backgroundColor function in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign random color to each card(div)
but some of them doesnt have color
how I fix it?
why is this hapanning

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    function generateRandomColor() {
        var randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        return randomColor;

    }
    var grid = document.querySelector(".grid");

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        grid.innerHTML += '<div class="card" ></div>';
       
        var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
      
        cards[i].style.backgroundColor = generateRandomColor();
      
    }
});
```

getting this
[image: what I am getting]

Comment: Try to check if `generateRandomColor` is producing valid color hex.
For Example - 
`function generateRandomColor() {
        var randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        return randomColor.length < 6 ? generateRandomColor() : randomColor;
    }`

Comment: Putting this in the answer section :)

Answer (score 1):

`generateRandomColor` function is not generating a valid color hex on each call.
So, try to check the length of color hex before returning it.

For Example -

```
function generateRandomColor() { 
    var randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);         
    return randomColor.length < 6 ? generateRandomColor() : randomColor;
}
```

Comment: A better approach would be to generate 6 random numbers 0-15, converting them to hex strings, and concatenating them. That way there's no possibility of invalid values.